# visual studio code SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with node . discord bot coding

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to coding when I try to run this command

```
var commando = require("discord.js-commando");
var yourbot = new commando.client();

yourbot.login('MzI1MDI2MzQ4NzEwMjMyMDY2.DCSP8Q.Xyn-k0_DfnV4x3WsKtfDPBM0KfU');
```

and then I type `node .` I get this

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/Desktop/Cyborg Pasta/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/index.js:4:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    Ians-MBP:Cyborg Pasta iankalman$ node .
    /Users/iankalman/Desktop/Cyborg Pasta/node_modules/discord.js-commando/src/client.js:144
            async setProvider(provider) {
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^`
```

Answer (score 0):

delete your node_modules folder and try reinstalling your modules with npm. Also, never post your bot token online you need to revoke that token.